# How to determine an app moving to a background state due to a phone call or due to the user pressing the home button

Tags: ios

I would like to perform a different action when my app moves to the background depending upon if its moving to that state because there is an incoming phone call, or if its moving to that state because the user has hit the home button.

In both cases the app delegate receives a willResignActive:, then a didEnterBackground: call. Therefore from the app delegate calls alone it would appear its not possible to determine the difference.
Is there some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UIApplicationDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) has a variety of methods for `Monitoring Application State Changes`.

Unfortunately (for you), *going into the background* is *going into the background*, there is no differentiation as to why. Given Apple's app design of walling everything off (for security reasons) I don't see them providing you details about what's going on on the phone outside your application.

I would certainly question the need for different behavior in those two cases, but I don't know the details of your app.

Comment: In one case the app will shortly be returned to the foreground automatically by the OS thus my view will be displayed (the content of which will be updated while in the background state), in the other the app won't be returned to the foreground and I need to schedule a local notification in that case.

Comment: i would either wait till `applicationWillTerminate:` to register your local notification or go ahead and register it, and unregister it when you come to the foreground

Comment: I'll do that, and also create an internal notification when the app is going to be suspended (from the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler block)

Comment: If I remember correctly, you are not allowed to update the display while in the background (at least with OpenGL ES; UIKit might be different). That's why all games display the 'paused' screen just after you resume the app.